# Google Play console 64 Bit error when the app is 64 bit

Tags: java, android

Google Play console is giving error to my 64 bit app bundle file.

We are trying to upload the 64bit & 32bit build, according to the recent Google policy change.

We have included respective abifilter `"ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'"` in the Build.gradle.

We were able to generate the build but when we upload the build to Play console it gives a warning saying "Release is not compliant with 64-bit Google Requirement".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A303g.jpg

We tried all approach, generating 4 builds (x86,x86_64,armeabi-v7a,arm64-v8a), generating two builds or uploading the universal build with all abifilter, it gives the same warning. We tried all possible approaches.

Please help us out in perfect steps of uploading the build to Play store or if we are making any mistake in generating the build please do let us know on that ends also.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('musicfree.jks')
            keyAlias 'musicfree'
            keyPassword 'musicfree'
            storePassword 'musicfree'
        }
    }


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.KeithAsford.DZRHRadio"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 20190826
        versionName "3.3.2"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    /* 4) Exclude duplicate licenses */
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    //for emotion string
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters '--utf16'
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }
}
```

Comment: read https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html

Comment: Possibly related: [Will playstore reject apps with armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86 but no x86-64 support?](//stackoverflow.com/q/55766256) except that you *are* building for x86-64.